# github clone a project with releases attachment

Tags: github

I use releases in one github project. I attach a binary to every release. I notice that cloning the project its dimension increments every time I create a new release.
My question is : attachments in releases affect project total size ? And if yes, there is some option to clone the project ignoring release attachments ?﻿

Comment: Do you need to attach the binary every time. If not you can use .gitignore files. See... http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore

Comment: You can also clone just a number of commits, using the `--depth` option.

Answer (score 0):

Attaching binaries to a github project release does not increase the repo size. They are stored outside of the repo somewhere. I couldn't find documentation specifying where/how, but testing shows that it's not in the repo.

I tested in a small repo by adding a 1MB binary to a release of a repo:

```
> du -hs .git/
400K    .git/
# At this point I uploaded 1MB attachment to release on github
> git pull
Already up-to-date.
> du -hs .git/
400K    .git/
```

Since the repo neither changed size nor indicated that changes was done in the git pull command, I conclude they are not stored in the repo.